# Extract & Sum List Per Participant & Location (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column that lists Participants and Locations Separately, and I'm attempting to extract values from other columns to sum to the participant and sum the location as separate formulas.

| Participants |
| --- |
| Jeff |
| Kim |
| Lucy |
| Frank |

| Location |
| --- |
| Grocery Store |
| Gas Station |
| Airport |
| Misc |

My issue is that I store the participant data in the same cell and I'm having troubles assigning them to their proper spots. My most successful approach was utilizing split remove all of the extra symbols that would prevent Sum from processing, but even when I attempt to sum those results, I'm encountering errors.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Transpose(SPLIT($C1:$C5, ";"))),"("&"*"&"*: "&")"))
```

| Location | Participants | Per Participant Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Grocery Store | Jeff | (Jeff: 5,25,10) |
| Gas Station | Jeff | (Jeff: 30,31) |
| Grocery Store | Kim; Lucy; Frank | (Kim: 15,15); (Lucy: 25,25); (Frank: 20,20,50); |
| Airport | Kim; Lucy; Frank | (Kim: 20,9,21); (Lucy: 25,35,15); (Frank: 20); |
| Misc | Kim; Lucy; Frank | (Kim: 10,10,15); (Lucy: 35,25); (Frank: 10,10,20,20); |

Desired Output

| Participants | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Jeff | 101 |
| Kim | 115 |
| Lucy | 185 |
| Frank | 170 |

| Location | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Grocery Store | 210 |
| Gas Station | 61 |
| Airport | 145 |
| Misc | 155 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach ***for just the*** `Participant` part:*

```js
=map(E2:E,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sum(ifna(filter(split(regexreplace(regexextract(C:C,Σ&"[^\)]*"),"[^\d,]",),","),regexmatch(C:C,Σ&":")))))))
```

[image]